# Force Auto Update Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have a mission critical application in the form of a chrome packaged app. This is an app that is installed via [Enterprise Policy](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelis). I've set up the auto update process however there are times when I need to force the update when the user logs in (I some times have breaking changes on the back-end that render older versions useless).

Currently if there is a new version available Chrome may or may not update right away when the user logs in. In my application I can detect the version and prompt the user to manually force an update but this is less than optimal. Users who are not overly familiar with Chrome can have trouble working through this process.

Ideally I would like to be able to have Chrome immediately look for and install updates on start up. Or allow the packaged app to force the update. Is that possible?